# Этимология слова "майдан"

Tags: этимология, лексика, значение-слов

Как произошло это слово? Что оно значит?

Answer (score 1):

Майдан в украинском - площадь. Это, думаю, все знают. Есть и производные слова, которые часто употребляются. Например, "Штрафной майданчик" (футб.), "дитячий майданчик" (детская площадка). Думаю, что само слово "майдан" в этом и других язках имеют общее происхождение. Возможно то, о котором вы пишите.

Интересно, что в казахском языке слово "майдан" переводится как "фронт, поле битвы; арена борьбы (военн.)". Есть производные "майдангер" - фронтовик, "майдандас" - однополчанин, "майдандасу" - конфронтация. (Каз-рус и рус-каз словарь. Сост. Косович, Секенова, 2012г.) Думаю, что изначально слово воспринималось именно как площадь (поле, арена), а уже позже ушло в военную сторону. О значении этого слова узнала от казаха. Он сказал, что слово переводится как "война", но это не самое популярное значение. Есть другое, более употребительное "соғыз". Подтверждения пока не нашла, если только слово "война" приравнять к "фронт". Но в целом значение слова "майдан" в казахском языке, как мне кажется, отходит от изначального значения "площадь" и тяготеет к военной терминологии.

Answer (score 1):

Слово, более близкое по звучанию к "майдан", было в санскрите и есть в современном татарском языке, где оно тоже означает "площадь" (можно предположить, что из него попало в украинский). Есть слово с близким звучанием и в других языках, но означать оно может совсем другое, напр. на основном диалекте китайского "майдан" означает "оплатить счёт", либо это сам "счёт" (в ресторане); два слога означают "купить" (май) + "лист, список" (дан).

В украинском это слово обозначает особый вид площади: это такой незастроенный участок, к которому сходятся несколько улиц (к этому "майдану" с холма спускаются Софийская, Малая Житомирская и др.). В общем случае площади называют словом "площа" - слово имеет чисто геометрический смысл, как и у нас "площадь", и в топонимике таких подавляющее большинство (нынешний "Майдан Незалежности" возник в результате переименования "площи Жовтневой революции"). Такое разъяснение приведено в сети от 1-го украинского телеканала.

Answer (score 1):

Я всегда считал, что слово фарси, пришло в украинский очевидным путем во времена Запорожской Сечи через турецкий, и уже оттуда - в ряд других языков. Не вижу и сейчас причин в этом сомневаться. Значение в тюркских в той или иной степени соответствует украинскому, все остальные версии из числа высказанных опровергаются соображением широкого распространения в тюркских и отсутствием в близких славянских.